# How can you make bold text if the font does not have "bold" included?

Tags: inkscape, fonts, path, readability, bold

I am working with some fonts, and none of them have the "bold" option.
The font is too thin, and the result is not well legible.

So, I was wandering: is there a way to turn the text into a path in some vector graphics software (Inkscape), and then transform the path so that the thickness of lettering increase, without changing (too much) the overall size of text, so to mimic the effect of using "bold" font?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to change a font to paths. Simply add some width to the stroke with the same color as the fill.

Just be aware of the type of corners you have.

[image]

Comment: It works great!
Thank you!

Comment: Ugh. As a typography aficionado, this makes me cringe. I don't have a better method, though, and I realise workarounds are workarounds. Grmbl. ;)

Comment: The size of the cringe depends on the width of the stroke.

Comment: I still wish there was a better way in 2024.